# Can't output MySQL table via web form

Tags: php, html-table, output

I am totally new to PHP and am trying to write up a simple web form that keeps track of some inventory and who borrowed it. I have LAMP setup on Ubuntu 13.10 w/PHP 5.5. I had no trouble writing the script that takes customer info and writes to MySQL db but am stuck on getting a script that outputs it. Looking at some examples and reading up I have this so far:

```
 <?php
ini_set("display_errors","on");
$dsn='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=inventory_form';
$username="****";
$password="*****";
$database="inventory_form";

try
    {
    $link=new PDO($dsn, $username,$password);
    echo 'Connection is established';
    }
catch (PDOException $e)
    {
    $error_message=$e->getMessage();
    echo "<h1>An error occurred: $error_message</h1>";
    }
$query="SELECT * from Inventory";
$result=$link->query($query);
/*/
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);


echo "<b><center>Database Output</center></b>";

?>
<table border="2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr> 
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Name</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Equipment Borrowed</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Service Tag</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Date Borrowed</font></th>
</tr>

<?php
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$first=mysql_result($result,$i,"FName");
$last=mysql_result($result,$i,"LName");
$Eq_Brwd=mysql_result($result,$i,"Eqpmnt_Brwd");
$Svc_tag=mysql_result($result,$i,"Service_Tag");
$Date_Bwd=mysql_result($result,$i,"Date_Taken");
?>

<tr> 
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo "$first $last"; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo "$Eq_Brwd"; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo "$Svc_tag"; ?></font></td>
<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo "$Date_Bwd"; ?></font></td>
</tr>
<?php
++$i;
} 
echo "</table>";


?>
```

All I get is the connection established message. One problem I know is the `$num` variable is not getting a value returned from `my_sql_num_rows`.I know there must be a simpler way to output the table info. Any suggestions or better way to this most welcome.

Reply: Now keeping it simple. I have this:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors","on");
$dsn='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=inventory_form';
$username="alank";
$password="alank";
$database="inventory_form";

try
    {
    $link=new PDO($dsn, $username,$password);
    echo 'Connection is established';
    }
catch (PDOException $e)
    {
    $error_message=$e->getMessage();
    echo "<h1>An error occurred: $error_message</h1>";
    }
$query="SELECT * from Inventory";
$result=$link->query($query);


echo "<b><center>Database Output</center></b>";

?>
<table border="2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tr> 
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Name</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Equipment Borrowed</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Service Tag</font></th>
<th><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Date Borrowed</font></th>
</tr>

<?php
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    echo '$row';

}

?>
```

But still no good. Output is:

> Connection is established
>   Database Output
>   $row$row$row$row$row$row$row
>   Name    Equipment Borrowed  Service Tag     Date Borrowed

Any advise. Sorry for so many questions. But that's how you learn. Appreciate your patience.

Comment: You haven't referenced any of the returned variables from PDO. Also, you're mixing PDO and `mysql_*` (`mysql_num_rows`) extensions, which are not mutually compatible.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT * from Inventory";
$result=$link->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

you will see how PDO works.

PDO functions and mysql_* functions belongs to two different extensions. you mixed them up.

Comment: I'm sorry but where do you put this in code.See above reply.